# Why bower-away is moving to bower to Yarn and not NPM

Tags: npm, frontend, nodes, bower, yarnpkg

I came across this nice module bower-away, which is helping us migrate our bower projects, since bower is deprecated.

However I am not clear with concept why would we migrate to Yarn and Not to NPM. is it only because NPM uses nested dependencies and Yarn uses flat dependency tree structure.

https://github.com/sheerun/bower-away

or is there any other reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because only Yarn allows for installing git repositories without
package.json (i.e. bower components) and is able to resolve semver
versions on git tags.

Comment: so that means bower components are git repositories

Comment: @sheerun just to make sure here, after bower-away procedure I want be able to run npm install for example and I need to use yarn only instead?

Comment: @Bart yarn is required afterwards

Comment: thank you @sheerun that is what I suspected, but would be glad if npm was still working with this...